# разделить строку по параметрам

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида **"1д1ч"** или **"1д1м"**, ну и тд. (если нет дней и часов, то обязательный параметр "м", тобишь минуты)

Как бы я мог это разделить на части?
Я подумал о регулярке split:
`((.*)д)?((.*)ч)?(.*)м` 
Понятное дело, что делит оно неправильно... (`['', '16д', '16', '1ч', '1', '1', '']`).
Да и сейчас я понимаю, что в любом случае я не смогу понять в списке вида [1, 1] что к чему относится... Так что, прошу помощи. 
Сразу благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
^(?!$)(?:(?P<day>\d+)д)?(?:(?P<hour>\d+)ч)?(?:(?P<minute>\d+)м)?$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/NWn99P/1). **Подробности**:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!$)` - тут же строка не должна заканчиваться
- `(?:(?P<day>\d+)д)?` - необязательная незахватывающая подмаска: одна и более цифр, захватываемые в подмаску "day", а потом буква `д`
- `(?:(?P<hour>\d+)ч)?` - необязательная незахватывающая подмаска: одна и более цифр, захватываемые в подмаску "hour", а потом буква `ч`
- `(?:(?P<minute>\d+)м)?` - необязательная незахватывающая подмаска: одна и более цифр, захватываемые в подмаску "minute", а потом буква `м`
- `$` - конец строки

[Пример использования в Python](https://ideone.com/gPN5Nl):

```py
import re
texts = ['1д1ч', '1д1м', '1д1ч1м']
for text in texts:
    m = re.search(r'^(?!$)(?:(?P<day>\d+)д)?(?:(?P<hour>\d+)ч)?(?:(?P<minute>\d+)м)?$', text)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

Результат:

```
{'day': '1', 'hour': '1', 'minute': None}
{'day': '1', 'hour': None, 'minute': '1'}
{'day': '1', 'hour': '1', 'minute': '1'}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: возвращает в таком виде: ['', '16', '1', '1', ''], можно ли как то это исправить?

Comment: я так понимаю, мне нужно взять и искать группы day, hour, minute?

Comment: @Anxious__ Покажите ваш код. Вы явно используете `split`. Кстати, если все `None` нужно заменить на `0`, см. [этот пример кода](https://ideone.com/osiGHx)

Comment: заменил split на search, все получилось. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Частенько подглядываю в ваши ответы, узнаю что-то новое. Спасибо.

Comment: @UModeL Тогда советую подписаться на [мой ютуб-канал](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw) :) Я там на английском рассказываю про регулярные выражения. Некоторые случаи совсем простые, но бывают и более интересные.